# MVC3 Custom validation attribute that compare valid minimum and maximum values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have 2 parameters in decimal for my model as following:

```
public class Range
{
     public decimal MinimumValue { get; set; }
     public decimal MaximumValue { get; set; }
}
```

Would it be possible to make custom validation for both parameters where:

- Validation for MinimmumValue (must be less than MaximumValue)
- Validation for MaximumValue (must be greater than MinimumValue)

Comment: What kind of validation do you use? Data annotation attributes?

Comment: Oh yes Data annotation

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of articles about creating custom validation attributes, but here is a sample of how it may look in your case:

```
public class GreaterThanAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string PropertyNameToCompare { get; set; }

    public GreaterThanAttribute(string propertyNameToCompare)
    {
        PropertyNameToCompare = propertyNameToCompare;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var propertyToCompare = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(PropertyNameToCompare);
        if (propertyToCompare == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(
                string.Format("Invalid property name '{0}'", PropertyNameToCompare));
        }
        var valueToCompare = propertyToCompare.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        bool valid;

        if (value is decimal && valueToCompare is decimal)
        {
            valid = ((decimal) value) > ((decimal) valueToCompare);
        }
        //TODO: Other types
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Compared properties should be numeric and of the same type.");
        }

        if (valid)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        return new ValidationResult(
            string.Format("{0} must be greater than {1}",
                validationContext.DisplayName, PropertyNameToCompare));
    }
}
```

I don't like very much the place where I start to check for property types, but I don't know if it's possible to make it nicer.

Of course you will need to implement `GreaterThanAttribute` too.

Answer (score 0):

I did a custom attribute to validade a field if checkbox is checked. If checkbox isn't checked the field is required, if not, the field isn't required. I can use this code to adapt and check if a field is greather than other.
You can also use data annotations extensions. More information about data annotations extensions [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/introducing-data-annotations-extensions)

```
public class RequiredIf : ConditionalValidationAttribute
{
    protected override string ValidationName
    {
        get { return "requiredif"; }
    }

    public RequiredIf(string dependentProperty, object targetValue)
        : base(new RequiredAttribute(), dependentProperty, targetValue)
    {
    }

    protected override IDictionary<string, object> GetExtraValidationParameters()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object> 
                    { 
                        { "rule", "required" }
                    };
    }
}


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
public abstract class ConditionalValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    protected readonly ValidationAttribute InnerAttribute;
    public string DependentProperty { get; set; }
    public object TargetValue { get; set; }
    protected abstract string ValidationName { get; }

    protected virtual IDictionary<string, object> GetExtraValidationParameters()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    protected ConditionalValidationAttribute(ValidationAttribute innerAttribute, string dependentProperty, object targetValue)
    {
        this.InnerAttribute = innerAttribute;
        this.DependentProperty = dependentProperty;
        this.TargetValue = targetValue;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        // get a reference to the property this validation depends upon
        var containerType = validationContext.ObjectInstance.GetType();
        var field = containerType.GetProperty(this.DependentProperty);
        if (field != null)
        {
            // get the value of the dependent property
            var dependentvalue = field.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

            // compare the value against the target value
            if ((dependentvalue == null && this.TargetValue == null) || (dependentvalue != null && dependentvalue.Equals(this.TargetValue)))
            {
                // match => means we should try validating this field
                if (!InnerAttribute.IsValid(value))
                {
                    // validation failed - return an error
                    return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage, new[] { validationContext.MemberName });
                }
            }
        }
        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = ValidationName,
        };
        string depProp = BuildDependentPropertyId(metadata, context as ViewContext);
        // find the value on the control we depend on; if it's a bool, format it javascript style
        string targetValue = (this.TargetValue ?? "").ToString();
        if (this.TargetValue.GetType() == typeof(bool))
        {
            targetValue = targetValue.ToLower();
        }
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("dependentproperty", depProp);
        rule.ValidationParameters.Add("targetvalue", targetValue);
        // Add the extra params, if any
        foreach (var param in GetExtraValidationParameters())
        {
            rule.ValidationParameters.Add(param);
        }
        yield return rule;
    }

    private string BuildDependentPropertyId(ModelMetadata metadata, ViewContext viewContext)
    {
        string depProp = viewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId(this.DependentProperty);
        // This will have the name of the current field appended to the beginning, because the TemplateInfo's context has had this fieldname appended to it.
        var thisField = metadata.PropertyName + "_";
        if (depProp.StartsWith(thisField))
        {
            depProp = depProp.Substring(thisField.Length);
        }
        return depProp;
    }
}
```

Comment: But if let say i wanted to use data annotation, the structure will be different right?

Comment: Structure about what? The use is like a normal annotation. You'll put [RequiredIf] attribute. In this my example you can use like it: [RequiredIf("OnRequest", true, ErrorMessageResourceName = "ValueRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Propertie))]